# Quartile calculation option in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics

I need to calculate the quartile value (e.g. 75%) of the pixels of a raster layer within a polygon file. I try to do that using QGIS, and found that the zonal statistics might be able to do that. But I only find the below options with the zonal statistics: Count; Sum; Mean; Median; StDev; Min; Max; Range; Minority; Majority; Variety.

Any solution to calculate the quartile value in QGIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use GRASS processing algorithms from withing QGIS. `v.rast.stats` should do what you require.

You could also probably use QGIS' native `Zonal histogram` but then you'd have to process the output yourself to find the quartiles from the unique value counts.

If you have only one polygon, or want it done over all of the raster which is covered by the union of the polygon features, you could clip the raster by the vector layer and then use GRASS `r.stats`, or QGIS native `Raster layer histogram`.

Comment: Thanks. v.rast.stats seems work. I am running that now.

Comment: Good to hear. Be careful about NODATA pixels, if that's relevant. GRASS and native QGIS don't always seamlessly communicate on what are NODATA values and this could throw off quantiles if present in your data set.

Comment: Now I have another question. I use "v.rast.stats" to calculate the "third_quartile" for a multipolygon file. I realize that it generates a lot of rows for each species (could be the same length with the occupied raster cells for each species). That makes the results really long, and the size is huge. Is there any way to only generate one row for each species?

Comment: @JianZhang, sorry this is exceeding my ability to visualize. However, you could try converting the multipolygons to polygons. And/or dissolving them?  GRASS does polygons differently than QGIS ("topologically", as a tiling of the mapping region with no gaps, overlaps etc), so I'd be a bit leery of throwing multipolygons into the mix. And maybe run `Fix geometry` on the vector layer? Just ideas...